# Wordpress: How to add some css files with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using this code to add a CSS file to my WordPress theme;

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/blue_grey.css" type="text/css" />');
```

but its not work!

how can i fix it?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to add stylesheets?

Comment: use `wp_head()`, `wp_footer()`, `wp_enqueue_scripts()` action hooks to add JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery('head')` instead of the `$`? It isn't uncommon for `$` to be something else in Wordpress installs

Comment: Yes, im tried jQuery('head') but its still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_head` or `echo` before `bloginfo()` like

```
href="<?php echo bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/blue_grey.css"
```

You can read the [best-way-to-create-a-css-file-dynamically](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/best-way-to-create-a-css-file-dynamically)

Comment: Im put an option to choose colors in my wp theme. and i have to do this with jquery!